# Elasticsearch (2.3.2) "not_analyzed" on identically named fields in different mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

An error occurs if I do the following:

1. Create an index with two mappings
2. Both mappings have the same field (in this case called `thing`)
3. Only one of the `thing` fields have `"index": "not_analyzed"`

The above can be done with the following calls:

```
DELETE /test/

PUT /test/
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "thing": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
    "page": {
      "properties": {
        "thing": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following error will then occur:

```
# DELETE /test/
{ ... }

# PUT /test/
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [page]: Mapper for [thing] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [thing] has different [index] values, mapper [thing] has different [omit_norms] values, cannot change from disable to enabled, mapper [thing] has different [analyzer], mapper [thing] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [omit_norms] across all types., mapper [thing] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [thing] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [page]: Mapper for [thing] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [thing] has different [index] values, mapper [thing] has different [omit_norms] values, cannot change from disable to enabled, mapper [thing] has different [analyzer], mapper [thing] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [omit_norms] across all types., mapper [thing] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [thing] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
         "reason": "Mapper for [thing] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [thing] has different [index] values, mapper [thing] has different [omit_norms] values, cannot change from disable to enabled, mapper [thing] has different [analyzer], mapper [thing] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [omit_norms] across all types., mapper [thing] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [thing] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Can someone explain why this is the case? Is this a bug?

Comment: read this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#merging-conflicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic "types" mechanism is virtual. Meaning, on the lower level (=lucene) all documents of an index are of the same "type". Elastic "type" division is done only by adding a "_type" field and filtering by it. That means you cannot have (on one index) 2 types with the same field_name and a different mapping - because on the lower level they are of the same type and they are in a conflict!
You defined "thing" in "product" type as not_analyzed, and in "page" you define it as "string" which defaults to "analyzed" - this is a different mapping and a conflict occurs! Either make them both the same or change one of the field names.

Comment: This seems likely and is backed up by the source @ymonad put on my question. The information about merging conflicts is the most relevent: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#merging-conflicts. Thanks for your answer.